# Avoid redirect on unauthorized with OpenIdConnect

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, auth0, backend-for-frontend

I am trying to setup a C# with React web application, using the C# backend as Backend-For-Frontend, so I can use cookie authentication. I am somewhat following [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-auth0-and-dotnet/#Configuring-the-ASP-NET-Core-Application), but using the newest C#/React template.

I can get the authentication to work, but if I try to hit an endpoint with the `[Authorize]` attribute, I get a 302 redirect to `/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=(...)`. I would like it to be a 401, if there is no valid authentication cookie yet.

Here is a screenshot from the network tab in developer tools (Edge):

[image: screenshot showing how the call is redirected.]

My authentication is registered in the `Program.cs` class, like this:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(o =>
{
    o.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    o.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    o.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("Auth0", options => AuthenticationExtensions.ConfigureOpenIdConnect(options, configuration));
```

The `AuthenticationExtensions.ConfigureOpenIdConnect()` looks like this. I have tried adding all the different events, I can imagine has anything to do with the redirect, but neither seems to have an effect:

```
internal static void ConfigureOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectOptions options, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    options.Authority = $"https://{configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}";

    options.ClientId = configuration["Auth0:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = configuration["Auth0:ClientSecret"];

    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
    options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost;

    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/callback");
    options.ClaimsIssuer = "Auth0";
    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = (context) =>
        {
            var logoutUri = $"https://{configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}/v2/logout?client_id={configuration["Auth0:ClientId"]}";

            var postLogoutUri = context.Properties.RedirectUri;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postLogoutUri))
            {
                if (postLogoutUri.StartsWith("/"))
                {
                    // transform to absolute
                    var request = context.Request;
                    postLogoutUri = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.PathBase + postLogoutUri;
                }
                logoutUri += $"&returnTo={Uri.EscapeDataString(postLogoutUri)}";
            }
            context.Response.Redirect(logoutUri);
            context.HandleResponse();

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        // I would expect one of these to work, but they don't.
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context => {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.HandleResponse();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context => {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.HandleResponse();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAccessDenied = context => {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            context.HandleResponse();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run into this with Cookie Auth. I solved it by overriding these events.

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(config =>
    {
        config.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

        config.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };

    });
```

Comment: This works. If anyone has some knowledge on why it has to be on Cookie options - and not OpenIdConnect options, that would be a great addition to the answer.